# Basics rules on UPDATE statement for relational MySql table: for vs while

Tags: php, mysql

I'm doing my first steps with mysql and php, so I have doubts on foundamental rules for a right code optimization.

I have a case where my `UPDATE` statement need to be executed on a certain number of rows, because it should be executed on a relational table, so is a for cicle correct?

```
<?
// connection already created
$data[] = array ("id" => 54, "enabled" => 1);
$data[] = array ("id" => 33, "enabled" => 0);
$data[] = array ("id" => 12, "enabled" => 0);
$data[] = array ("id" => 58, "enabled" => 0);
$data[] = array ("id" => 21, "enabled" => 1);
$data[] = array ("id" => 10, "enabled" => 1);
$data[] = array ("id" => 18, "enabled" => 0);
$data[] = array ("id" => 32, "enabled" => 1);
$data[] = array ("id" => 84, "enabled" => 0);
$data[] = array ("id" => 80, "enabled" => 1);

for (var $i = 0; $i < count ($data); $i ++) {

    $id = $data[$i]["id"];
    $enabled = $data[$i]["enabled"];

    $sql = "UPDATE users SET user_enabled = '$enabled' WHERE user_id = '$id' LIMIT 1;";
    $res = mysql_query ($sql);
    $num = mysql_num_rows ($res);

}


?>
```

Should I use a `while` or a `for` loop?
Is this code valid for multiple UPDATEs or does exist something better like specific queries for this kind of action?

Comment: If the number of records you need to update is large enough, it's sometimes better to do a single bulk INSERT into a temporary table, and then UPDATE the target table via a JOIN with the temporary table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several comments:

- Calculating the `count($data)` on every iteration of the loop is a needless cost.  Either start the loop at `count($data)` and count *down*, or else as @Ignacio suggests, use `foreach`.
- This is a great example where it would be a benefit to use a prepared query with parameters.  But this feature is not supported in PHP's plain mysql extension.  You would have to use mysqli or preferably [PDO](https://www.php.net/pdo).
- You don't have to put quotes around integer values in an SQL expression.
- `mysql_num_rows()` is meaningless for an `UPDATE` query.  You probably meant to use `mysql_affected_rows()`.
- I don't know why you use `LIMIT` in this query, since I would guess that `user_id` is the primary key of the `users` table, and therefore you would never update more than one row anyway.

Here is how I would write that code:

```
<?php
// PDO connection already created
$data[] = array ("id" => 54, "enabled" => 1);
...etc...

$sql = "UPDATE users SET user_enabled = :enabled WHERE user_id = :id";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

foreach ($data as $parameters) {

    $success = $stmt->execute($parameters);
    $num = $stmt->rowCount();

}


?>
```

Answer (score 3):

With a sequence of finite length you should use a [`foreach`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a [**RecursiveArrayIterator**](http://www.php.net/~helly/php/ext/spl/classRecursiveArrayIterator.html)

```
<?
// connection already created
$data[] = array ("id" => 54, "enabled" => 1);
$data[] = array ("id" => 33, "enabled" => 0);
$data[] = array ("id" => 12, "enabled" => 0);
$data[] = array ("id" => 58, "enabled" => 0);
$data[] = array ("id" => 21, "enabled" => 1);
$data[] = array ("id" => 10, "enabled" => 1);
$data[] = array ("id" => 18, "enabled" => 0);
$data[] = array ("id" => 32, "enabled" => 1);
$data[] = array ("id" => 84, "enabled" => 0);
$data[] = array ("id" => 80, "enabled" => 1);

$data = new RecursiveArrayIterator($data);

for (var $i = 0; $i < count ($data); $i ++) {

    $id = $data[$i]["id"];
    $enabled = $data[$i]["enabled"];

    $sql = "UPDATE users SET user_enabled = '$enabled' WHERE user_id = '$id' LIMIT 1;";
    $res = mysql_query ($sql);
    $num = mysql_num_rows ($res);

}


?>
```